# Pointer-to-Member and static variable

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

Why I can't have [pointer to member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx) like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* malloc, free, rand */
using namespace std;

class Pool{};

struct FE{
    static Pool pool;
};

Pool FE::pool;

int main() {
    Pool FE::* pmd = &FE::pool;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/UabI61

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pool` is a global variable that happens to live in the scope of `FE`; pointers to members only point to members of *instances* of classes.

Comment: So - can this be fixed somehow? Can I have pointer to static variable?

Comment: @tower120 like I said, it is a normal variable. Just do `Pool* p = &FE::pool;`

Answer (score 4):

Pointer-to-members are essentially offsets into an object. That is, if you have an `FE` object a pointer-to-member indicates a constant offset from the address of each `FE` object. A `static` object won't have a constant offset from each `FE` object. Thus, the type of `&FE::pool` is `Pool*` and not `Pool FE::*`. The two pointer types are incompatible.

Comment: Note `Pool *the_pool = &(FE::pool);` will compile. To be clear, if the above was a little confusing.